# mail() not working when executed by web server

Tags: php, email, postfix-mta

Details:

- OS: CentOS
- Web Server: apache 2.2
- PHP version: 5.3.3
- MTA: Postfix

`sendmail.php`:

```
<?php
    mail('example@example.com','subject','message');
?>
```

When I type the command `php sendmail.php`, this function is working normal, but when executed by web server through brower, `mail()` is not working.

Why is it happening?

Comment: Perhaps your binary `php` isn't shared with apache and therefore uses a different .ini file which in turn has the wrong settings for sendmail

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but I'd dump `mail()` altogether and use PHPMailer or SwiftMailer instead.

Comment: are you using localhost???

Comment: is it throwing an error? or just silently failing? What is the return value of mail()?

Comment: That should be affected by SELinux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, when working on Centos and I have issues where things work on the command line and not in browser it is a SELinux issue. Trying checking the status of SELinux by typeing

> getenforce

If SELinux is enforcing, temporarily set it to permissive mode by typing

> `setenforce 0`

Retry the mail function. If it succeeds you've got issues with SELinux labeling.

Here are two links to help you with that.

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/Tutorials/Permissive_versus_enforcing
http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux

Basically you'll need to relabel the processes that the browser is trying to use to 'httpd_sys_content_t' you can check the current labels by listing the directory where your php file is residing. with the Z option

```
cd /var/www/html/    
ls -lahZ
```

your label should like something like this:

```
-rwxrwx-rx. root apache(whatever your apache user  group is) unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0
```

If it doesn't look like that, apache can't execute the file and that's why it's not sending.

To change the label you need to execute chcon on the file(s) that are giving you issues:

```
cd /var/www/html/project_directory
chcon -v --type=httpd_sys_content_t sendmail.php
```

Also note that setenforce 0 will not persist a reboot and you should turn SELinux back to enforcing with

```
setenforce 1
```

After proving that the mail will send in SELinux permissive mode, if the above does not fix your problem, the next issue could be SELinux booleans. you can see a list of all the booleans with this command:

```
getsebool -a
```

This is a pretty daunting list, and we only want the booleans dealing with apache, httpd. So lets grep for that and pipe it through less.

```
getsebool -a | grep 'httpd' | less
```

That gives us a much more manageable list. You should see a boolean called

```
httpd_can_sendmail
```

It probably looks like this:

```
httpd_can_sendmail --> off
```

We want that to be turned on. You do that with this command

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail on
```

Note the -P, that makes this change persist a machine reboot.
http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/SelinuxBooleans

Comment: Thanks.
when typing `setenforce 0`,the mail function is working normal,
when typing `ls -Z`,the label is the same as your label,
Why?

Comment: See my edit above. I'm guessing it is because the SELinux boolean httpd_can_sendmail is set to off.